# How to copy txt file online, put into server ssh or ftp?

Tags: file-upload, ssh

I'm in the process of installing Django on a GoDaddy server, (i know i know), and i need to copy this script, https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py,  into a directory on the server. I have ssh access but I'm not quite sure what the right syntax would be to actually copy the file. I tried `cp` and `scp` but apparently I'm not doing it right. I'm on a mac terminal, fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not download it directly from your ssh session:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about wget. Will it download to the current directory?
I also got this error, ERROR: certificate common name `*.a.ssl.fastly.net' doesn't match requested host name `raw.github.com'.
To connect to raw.github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.

Comment: it looks like there's issue with SSL certificate on `raw.github.com`, just add `--no-check-certificate` after `wget`

Comment: After adding nocheck, I got this prompt: WARNING: certificate common name `*.a.ssl.fastly.net' doesn't match requested host name `raw.github.com'.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 114330 (112K) [text/plain]
virtualenv.py: Permission denied

Cannot write to `virtualenv.py' (Success). I don't understand how if the permission was denied why it returned Success. I tried sudo and su as well.

Comment: might be an issue with GoDaddy ssh session. Is it a dedicated hosting?

Comment: Yes, I do believe that it is dedicated.